# JavaFX ObservableList prevent auto selection

Tags: java, javafx, observablelist

I have an application which uses JavaFX. It contains a ListView (which uses a ObservableList). I added a ChangeListener using

```
list.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener...
```

and it works fine. Every time I select an oher item, the listener is called.

But it is also called when I remove an element from the ObservableList.
After the element is removed, an other element of the list is automatically selected and the listener is called.

How can I prevent this behaviour?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to remove the listener, delete the item, then re-add the listener.  Where to do this depends on your code, but probably where the item gets deleted or in a list change listener using getRemoved().

Answer (score 1):

In case my comment was too cryptic;

```
package listchange;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ListChange extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ObservableList<String> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        data.addAll("one","two","three","four");

        ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                System.out.println("new val "+newValue);
            }
        };

        ListView lv = new ListView(data);
        lv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(changeListener);

        data.addListener(new ListChangeListener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change<? extends String> c) {
                c.next();
                if (c.wasRemoved()){
                    lv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                }
            }
        });

        Button b = new Button("delete");
        b.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                //you can remove listener here or in data ListChangeListener
                //lv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().removeListener(changeListener);
                if (data.size() > 0) data.remove(0);
                //you have to re-add the listener after removing
                lv.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(changeListener);
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        root.getChildren().addAll(lv,b);

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

}
```

This way you'll still get selection changed events when traversing using keys.  If you know where the deletion takes place, it's easy to just remove and then re-add the listener.

Comment: Thanks i got it.
I found an other solution that works for me very good. I set a flag just before I remove an element from the list. In the selection-handler method I check this flag and if it´s true I just ignore the event (and set the flag back to flase).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
final ObservableList<String> fruits = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Apple", "Banana", "Pear", "Strawberry", "Peach", "Orange", "Plum", "Melon", "Cherry", "Blackberry", "Melon", "Cherry", "Blackberry");
final ComboBox fruit = new ComboBox(fruits);

fruit.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<String>() {
    public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends String> ov, String old_val, String new_val) {
        //TODO: your remove method
    }
});
```

Comment: Any component you can use for `ComboBox` instead of `ListView` with `final lv = new ...`

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that works, but it is not a good solution.

Instead of using a listener for selection changes, i only handle mouse click events on the list. When I receive a click event, I request the selected element from the ListView.
This is not called when I remove or add an element. Just when clicking on the list.